# First result in a returned list - CosmosDB query

Tags: typescript, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am learning the CosmosDB SQL API for JS and am having what I believe is a basic issue in understanding Typescript.  The function I'm calling returns a group of items, which are just JSON objects.  In my query, however, I just want to replicate the SQL aggregate function to count total records.  Long story short, how do I return just a single simple integer for the number of items returned by the query?

```
export class AssetTypeRepository extends BaseRepository<AssetType> {
    -- A SIMPLE FUNCTION TO RETURN THE NUMBER OF RECORDS IN A SET
     count(): Promise<number> {
        const { resources: items } = this._container.items
            .query("select count(1) as recordCount from c")
            .fetchAll()[0]; -- SHOULD I JUST GET INDEX 0 SINCE AN AGGREGATE WILL RETURN EXACTLY ONE ROW?
        
        return Promise.resolve(/* just a plain ol' integer goes here, right? */);
    }
}
```

Here's an example from some documentation, but it's returning items, not a scalar value.

```
const querySpec: SqlQuerySpec = {
  query: "SELECT * FROM Families f WHERE f.lastName = @lastName",
  parameters: [
    {name: "@lastName", value: "Hendricks"}
  ]
};
const {result: items} = await items.query(querySpec).fetchAll();
```

Most of this is based on lines 33-48 [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-cosmos-db-sql-api-nodejs-getting-started/blob/a754ffb322b8b0f424ec67db80c71a6d63834c2a/app.js#L33).

Answer (score 3):

`COUNT(1)` returns a document, with a property representing the count, something like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM C
```

```json
[
    {
        "$1": 123
    }
]
```

You can alias the `$1`, with something like:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(1) AS MyCount FROM C
```

```json
[
    {
        "MyCount": 123
    }
]
```

To return just a scalar value, use `VALUE COUNT(1)`:

```sql
SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) FROM c
```

```json
[
    123
]
```

Comment: That's really helpful SQL API syntax help.  I'll definitely use it.  But what does the TS need to look like there?

const { resources: items } = this._container.items
   .query("select value count(1) as recordCount from c")
   .fetchAll()[0];